# Open popup onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open pop-up on exit (Not "stay on page or leave" box). I can't get this working. Where do I make mistake ?

```
 function poponload()
{
testwindow = window.open("http://www.google.com", "mywindow",     
"location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=5,height=5,left=100,top=100");
}

$(document).ready(function () {

window.onbeforeunload = function () { 

poponload();

});


$(window).unload(function () {

poponload();

});


});
```

Comment: Your mistake is trying to open a popup on exit...

Comment: I wish. But unfortunetly, not a mistake in today's world.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a syntax error.  You have an extraneous parenthesis after the onbeforeunload function assignment.  Remove it and see if that fixes your issue.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 

poponload();

};
```